# I can't get my test accuracy to increase in a sentiment analysis

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, svm, text-classification

I'm not sure if this is the right place but my test accuracy is always at about .40 while I can get my training set accuracy to 1.0. I'm trying to do a sentiment analysis of tweets on trump, I have annotated each tweet with a positive,negative or neutral polarity. I want to be able to predict the polarity of new data based on my model. I've tried different models but the SVM seems to give me the highest test accuracy. I'm unsure as to why my data model accuracy is so low but would appreciate any help or direction.

```
trump = pd.read_csv("trump_data.csv", delimiter = ";")

#drop all nan values
trump = trump.dropna()
trump = trump.rename(columns = {"polarity,,,":"polarity"})

#print(trump.columns)
def tokenize(text):
   ps = PorterStemmer()
   return [ps.stem(w.lower()) for w in word_tokenize(text)    


X = trump.text

y = trump.polarity
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = .2, random_state = 42)


svm = Pipeline([('vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stopwords.words('english'), 
tokenizer=tokenize)), ('svm', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2',alpha=1e-3, 
random_state=42,max_iter=5, tol=None))])

svm.fit(X_train, y_train)


model = svm.score(X_test, y_test)
print("The svm Test Classification Accuracy is:", model )
print("The svm training set accuracy is : {}".format(naive.score(X_train,y_train)))
y_pred = svm.predict(X)
```

This is an example of one of the strings in the text column of the dataset

".@repbilljohnson congress must step up and overturn president trumpâ€™s discriminatory #eo banning #immigrants & #refugees #oxfam4refugees"

[Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqryY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `naive.score`? I assume it's a `copy-paste` mistake. Here are a few steps you can follow.

1. Make sure you enough data points and clean it. `Cleaning` the dataset is the inevitable process in data science.
2. Make use of the parameters like `ngram_range, max_df, min_df, max_features` while featurizing the text with either [TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) or [CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html). You may also try embeddings using [Word2Vec](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/).
3. Do a hyperparameter tuning on `alpha, penalty` & other variables using [GridSearch](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) or [RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html). Make sure you are `CV` currently. Refer the documentation for more info
4. If the dataset is `imbalanced`, then try using other matrices like `log-loss, precision, recall, f1-score, etc`. Refer [this](https://sachinkalsi.github.io/blog/category/ml/2018/08/20/top-8-performance-metrics-one-should-know.html) for more info.
5. Make sure your model is neither `overfitted` not `underfitted` by checking train-error & test error.

Other than `SVM`, also try the traditional models like `Logistic Regression`, `NV`, `RF` etc. If you have a large number of data points, then you may try Deep Learning models.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to clean the polarity data set as it had values such as "positive," , "positive,," and "positive,,," hence not registering them as different so I just removed all "," from the column.